# How to use secure streaming in FlowPlayer?

Tags: amazon-ec2, flowplayer, wowza, secure-coding

I am using FlowPlayer to stream using RTMP from Wowza using Amazon EC2 instance for the file stored in Amazon S3 bucket. I want the streaming to be secure. In flow player we can accomplish that. [Secure Streaming](http://flowplayer.org/demos/plugins/streaming/secure-wowza.html)

If we include the secret token in javascript as shown, it can easily be read by anyone. So it is not so much secure. Another way mentioned is to compile the FlowPlayer source file. I couldn't find any tutorial regarding this. Can anyone tell me which file to edit and what to edit ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compiling flowplayer isn't simple at all. they have detailed instructions here:
http://flowplayer.org/documentation/developer/development-environment.html

They conveniently do not tell you what and where to hardcode the token. I'm still trying to figure it out. Took me 4 hours to get the environment setup.

you basically need java JDK (get the 32bit even if you're on x64), ant, and flex framework.
I'll let you know if I find where to compile the token.

K so once you get the compilng working, all you need to do is change the existing token string in your securestreaming source which is located in the following file:

src\actionscript\org\flowplayer\securestreaming\Config.as

Comment: Thanks. But I wonder is that secure ? I mean, IE caches the swf file in your temp. So anyone who has the swf can decompile to get the token.

Comment: No, that is not secure. There are some alternatives which might give you better security, like the one-time-password approach offered by [Wrench](http://wowzatoolbox.com/wrench).